# How to concat two JArray with json4s in Scala?

Tags: scala, json4s

I get data from REST API. I need to do a few request and concat array from each request into one Json.

```
//getting body of response

val json = parse(body)

val data = json \ "data"

//...

//... other request of data

val json_other = parse(body_other)

val data_other = json \ "data"
```

Both `data` and `data_other` are JArray values.

How can I concat them in one JArray?

Comment: data ++ data_other ... should work

Comment: Looks like it. And in general, the `++` operation seems to be defined on the more generic `JValue` like this: https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/6acb70317606800ec02751eafdc45a1e0bda5dd6/ast/shared/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JValue.scala#L61-L80

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)